Improving the appearance of statistics frames in my data reduction software (Python, custom/themed tkinter)
I am building mass spec data reduction software in Python for a niche scientific instrument, and could use some advice on how to make my statistics look less amateurish. The target audience is mostly research scientists and graduate students.
First, I am using customtkinter/themed tkinter over standard tkinter as much as possible, which has significantly improved the looks of the software, however, the statistics panel is still something I'm struggling with.
I might want to migrate to PySide6 in the future, but for now, I'd really prefer to stick with ctk/ttk. Maybe this is the sunk cost fallacy, but I want to get my software working fully before breaking and rebuilding the GUI and I'm just getting the hang of ttk/ctk.
There are two statistics panels in the software, both on the left-hand side above the buttons:

The above GUI shows the raw data for each analysis. The user can click on any datum to remove it as an outlier, and the statistics frame will automatically update. The colors of the data here have to match the colors in our mass spec interface software and can't be changed. The user can also click on any analysis in the right-hand list and view it directly, rather than using the Next/Previous buttons underneath the stats frame. The checkmark in the list next to each analysis name indicates that the analysis has been viewed and reduced, so analyses that haven't been viewed/reduced will appear with an empty checkbox.

The above 'quality control' GUI shows all analyses in the sequence. The plots are a bit of a clusterfuck, but this intended for outlier identification and removal, so a clusterfuck is actually a good thing here. Like the previous plots, the user can click on a line to identify the analysis as an outlier and remove it from further calculations, and the stats frame will automatically update. The user can also hover their mouse over any given line to see the label/name given to the analysis. Lastly, the user has a button above the lower right hand plot to toggle between viewing 2 amu (hydrogen) and 40 amu (argon), both equally useless in 95% of scenarios. Note that the height of the statistics frame in this GUI is dynamic and based on the analysis types present, so I can't align it with the top of the buttons like with the previous stats frame. The colors here are flexible, though, unlike the previous plot.

The sequence selector is a separate GUI that has no stats frame. I'm pretty happy with this, minus the whitespace below the options (more will be added later) but I thought I'd toss it in to see if anyone has any suggestions!
I'm honestly pretty happy with most of the way the software looks, but like I said, I've been struggling with how to make the statistics frames look more professional. I'd be happy to take any general advice that anyone has, though!

Is the problem actually the UX or is it the graphical design? Since there is a SE site for the latter as well.

@jazZRo What's that SE site? this is the only one that came up in my search

I should have added the link. Here it is: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Thanks. I guess the problem is a bit of both so I've posted it over there, too (and they pointed me here, lol). It's a question about how I can use graphic design principles to improve UX.

If you want to apply graphic/visual design principles to improve UX, you can start by thinking about the three basic guidelines of Rhythm, Repetition and Pattern or perhaps the Gestalt Principles (with examples) that should apply to all of the user interface and not just the side panel.
Personally, I find it a bit difficult having to look on the left hand side panel for information relating to the graphs in the centre of the screen, as it requires you to continually move your focus from one side to another. I imagine that you can just show these values on or below the graph to make it easier for the user.
You would also be surprised at how by simply reducing the number of alignment points for the layout will make things look at bit more professional, as it create a less cluttered design visually. So things like aligning the top of the side panels to the top of the graphs, aligning the headings of the left side panel, and also cleaning up the design and alignment of the tables.
Data visualization design is a specialization of UX design, and it does require both knowledge of the dataset plus the principles of visual design to make it tell the story you want it to (or make the decisions you need to).

Adding the data to each plot was something I struggled with and ultimately decided against: there isn't a 'good' location to consistently place the stats without potentially covering up data, especially when the data are highly scattered. Furthermore, placing the statistics on the left with the raw data creates repetition with the statistics in the next window, which can't be added to the plots.
Your note about alignment points rang true, and has resulted in the following improvements: https://imgur.com/a/vP0gKg8
I'll work on the table in the third image next. Thank you!
